# How to get the linker in gcc to recognize OpenCL library functions?

Tags: xcode, gcc, makefile, opencl

I'm getting my feet wet with OpenCL. I'm sure this problem is not specific to OpenCL, however.

the top of my main file looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

// some code

cl_device_id device_id; //declaring a device id gives no errors

int err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
//the above API call does give an error.
```

I'm doing this on Snow Leopard. I can build and run Apple's examples using XCode. I can also  compile and run NVIDIA's sample code by running make.

How do I properly compile my code without using XCODE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ gcc -framework OpenCL hello.c
```

and

```
$ gcc -framework opencl hello.c
```

both work. Anyone want to try this on a non-OSX environment?

Answer (score 0):

I built some simple examples using Eclipse CDT.
I needed to also change `#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>` to `#include <opencl.h>` outside of XCode, and add `-I /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers` (or something similar).